# How to get the size of the displayed Text in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a way to determine the size of displayed text in a multi-column `TextBox` to set the `Scrollbars` property to the correct value.

Since it is some sort of enhanced `MessageBox` what I work on, the size of the `MessageBox` should be determined from the height and the width of the text sourced by strings with newlines in it.

Currently I use this code to determine the size of the `MessageBox` depending on the text to be entered. But you see the `MessageBox` has a `MaximiumSize` determined. The TextBox for the text itself has `WordWrap` enabled, too. So the only thing undefined is the `Height` of the text after inserting it to TextBox.Text.

```
SizeF textSize = this.tbxText.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(message, this.tbxText.Font);

int frmWidth = picWidth + (int)textSize.Width;
if (frmWidth > this.MaximumSize.Width)
{
    frmWidth = this.MaximumSize.Width;
}
else if (frmWidth < this.MinimumSize.Width)
{
    frmWidth = this.MinimumSize.Width;
}

int frmHeight = picHeight + (int)textSize.Height + pnlButtons.Height + pnlInput.Height;
if (frmHeight > this.MaximumSize.Height)
{
    frmHeight = this.MaximumSize.Height;
}
else if (frmHeight < this.MinimumSize.Height)
{
    frmHeight = this.MinimumSize.Height;
}
```

Setting the `TextBox.Scrollbars` Property to Both as default lets a disabled Scrollbar on the screen that is not really nice nor wanted.
Sadly, the `Graphics.MeasureString` does not help really, since it does not consider `WordWrap` behaviour.

So, how can I determine if the `TextBox.Text` is leaving the visible area making a vertical Scrollbar needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty simple, using a `RichTextBox` that has pretty different features, such as `Scrollbars` that are only displayed if needed and not displayed disabled like on the normal `TextBox`.

With the `RichTextBox` I can just set the `ScrollBars` Property to both and it will manage that right.

Answer (score 2):

I would continue to use `Graphics.MeasureString`, but you need to add logic that will simulate a word wrap by dividing the resulting string width with the control width (ie, you calculate how textbox widths fit in your string width) to get your rows and then multply the string height by this.

Note however that Graphics.MeasureString is not entirely accurate, however as a rough guess for scrolling support it might suffice - as always, test this out.

Answer (score 1):

Some controls have AutoSize property who shrink/grow by size of controls inside or by text , maybe you don't need to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

One of `Graphics.MeasureString` overloads takes a `width` argument, (maximum width of the string in pixels).

So, the size needed to render the message in the above example might be:

```
SizeF textSize = this.tbxText.CreateGraphics()
    .MeasureString(message, this.tbxText.Font, this.tbxText.Width);
...
```

For other `Graphics.MeasureString` overloads, see: [MeasureString overloads (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  I had a UserControl with a text-box that I wanted to display without scroll bars, no matter what size it ended up.  (That particular user-control is a pane in a window, and the window can be either in portrait or landscape orientation, and I didn't want to have two user-controls for each layout -- that seemed dumb.)

This code, in the Load event-handler, did it for me:

```
int iLine = textbox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textbox1.TextLength - 1) + 1;
int iHeight = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.textbox1.Text, this.textbox1.Font).Height;
float fTextHeight = iHeight * ((float)iLine + 0.25f /* fudge factor */);
textbox1.Size = new Size (textbox1.Size.Width, (int)fTextHeight);
```

[This forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/87a668d5-5fa8-44f0-a831-94f4e82db8ca/lines-per-page-in-rich-text-box?forum=winforms) suggested the use of `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`.